# Adsense says 22 page views, Google Analytics says 281

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

Adsense is telling me I have 22 page views, while GA says 281.

My web app is accessed via two different domains, one for Australia and the other for the US. Since it's the same app I'm using the same GA and Adsense accounts on both (same code).

When I look at GA it says I've had 281 pageviews, and Adsense says I've had 22. For Australia the discrepancy is only around 10% for the USA it's 10x. So something seems wrong.

Do you have any ideas/clues for what I should be looking for.

Many thanks

Comment: 90% of your users have ad blocking software installed.

Comment: That's what I thought initially. But I also have US traffic hitting the Australian website, and on that the US visitors are viewing ads at least 2/3 of the time. I suspect there's something configuration related.

Comment: Adview rate for US visitors is higher than 2/3 but was 2/3 when I had a little spike because someone posted to reddit. I find it hard to believe that the general public is blocking ads at a much higher rate than redditors.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. So it was a config issue, had to add my site in settings > site authorisation to the 'authorised sites' list. So this was a silly question, but might be useful for those who forget they've restricted which sites can earn Adsense income for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a config issue, had to add my site in settings > site authorisation to the 'authorised sites' list.

So this was a silly question, but might be useful for those who forget they've restricted which sites can earn Adsense income for them.

Answer (score 1):

Having different stats is very common and the cause varies. Adsense never tracks stats from users who have ad blocking software enabled, and which isn't the case with Analytics. Depending on what the visiting user has, the stats vary.